# Pubnub "Invalid JSON" with forward slash

Tags: pubnub

When I try to publish a message containing a forward slash PubNub rejects the message as "Invalid JSON". I am using the Go library.

It could be something like this:

`go pubnub.Publish("MY-CHANNEL", "someth/ing", successChannel, errorChannel)`

or the message might be a little more complex like this:

```
    message := struct {
        Name   string `json:"name"`
        Phone  string `json:"phone"`
        Type   string `json:"type"`
    }{
        "Foo/bar",
        "555-555-5555",
        "customer",
    }
```

The response is always
`ERROR: [0, "Invalid JSON", 400, "MY-CHANNEL"]`

Removing the forward slash always resolves the issue. Unfortunately, with my actual use case I cannot do without them.

Is this a bug with PubNub?

Comment: I will have our Go engineer review this. Stay tuned.

Comment: This code worked for us with or without the "/". Can you provide a gist or other online means to share full code that reproduces this issue so we can give it a *go*. ;)

Comment: Thanks Craig, this is how I am trying to publish. I've redacted my keys and channel. https://gist.github.com/louishawkins/4d5a4b27e202158ba849bc96556eb7f5

Comment: This is the final URL for the HTTP "GET" request: https://gist.github.com/louishawkins/a8550b9ed09433a8316ab433495710bf Decoding the string results in valid JSON.

Comment: what was the problem? @LouisHawkins